# 404 Error WordPress

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I am trying to open my website but it keeps giving me a **404 error**. I checked multiple sources and tried different solutions to solve the error, for example, I have tried:

- permalinks changes
- `.htaccess` file current code:

  ```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>)**
  ```

However, the problem still exists. Also, after doing the desired changes now I am getting the following error:

> This page isn’t working paracha.tech redirected you too many times.
>   Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Let me know if anyone can help.

Thanks

Comment: can you provide plugin lists from website, which may have feature to redirect pages/posts?

Comment: plugin list:   

Akismet Anti-Spam,
Contact Form 7,
Debug This,
Envato WordPress Toolkit,
Hello Dolly,
Limit Login Attempts,
MailChimp Widget,
Master Slider Pro,
ozythemes Logistic Theme Essentials,
Sidekick,
Slider Revolution,
Widget Importer & Exporter,
Wordfence Security,
WordPress Importer,
WP 404 Auto Redirect to Similar Post,
WPBakery Visual Composer.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing a similar problem but I solved it with the help of these simple steps.

Go to Settings > General and click Save Changes.

Go to Settings > Permalinks and click on save changes

Comment: I have realised that `.htaccess` file had to be regenerated

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > General and check what you have for Site Address and WordPress Address. The site address should be where you want the front end of the site to be, and the WordPress address is where your WordPress files live.

Based on the htaccess code you posted, it sounds like both of these settings should be your regular domain name without anything changed.

Also, sometimes after making these changes, you have to flush your permalinks settings. So, go to Settings > Permalinks and just click the Save Changes button again.

Comment: Thank you BMartin for your answer. My Site and WordPress Address is the same which I believe is correct.

What do you mean by "Based on the htaccess code you posted, it sounds like both of these settings should be your regular domain name without anything changed."

Thanks

Comment: Well you could change RewriteRule ^index.php and RewriteRule . index.php [L] to point to different locations, if you had set your WordPress or Site Address to different locations, but it looks like you haven't done that.

Comment: Could you be missing the index.php file? Maybe check your root folder to make sure that exists.

Comment: The index.php file exists in the root directory. 

I have also noticed when I log in my WordPress's backend. My site seems to load just fine otherwise I get the errors as stated earlier.

Comment: Well I'm out of ideas :( Like a commenter said above, see if any of your plugins are doing redirects. Try a different theme just to see if that's the issue. I hope someone else will have the answer.

Comment: I will try the different theme option but thank you so much for your responses. You are doing an incredible job!!

Comment: You mentioned a plugin called WP 404 Auto Redirect to Similar Post, so that could be the culprit. The rest should be okay.

Comment: Hello, I'm the developer of the said plugin. Well, the plugin takes only action when a 404 is about to be displayed. So if his homepage doesn't work and actually trigger a 404 error, there's a big problem in his website configuration.

I would suggest him to disable every single plugin, visit "Admin > Settings > Permalinks" (in order to flush permalinks). If the website starts to work again, re-activate the first plugin and test website again. Then go to next plugin etc... etc...

Answer (score 0):

In my specific scenario, I made modifications to the configuration file located at "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf". Specifically, I changed the value of "AllowOverride" from "None" to "All".

Here is the updated configuration after changing the settings in the "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf" file:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After that restart the apache server.